# Why the function doesn't alert onclick?

Tags: javascript, onclick, dom-events

I'm not too sure why the code below doesn't work in the browser. Any ideas?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<script>
  function click() {
    alert("You clicked on a paragraph");
  }
</script>

<body>
  <p onclick="click()" id="paragraph">This is a paragraph</p>
</body>

</html>
```

I figured out how to do the above with the `document.getElementById` function (see below).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<script>
  function click() {
    alert("You clicked on a paragraph");
  }
</script>

<body>
  <p id="paragraph">This is a paragraph</p>
</body>

<script>
  document.getElementById("paragraph").onclick = function() {
    click();
  }
</script>

</html>
```

My question is why the first approach doesn't work?

Comment: You can get more information about HTML, CSS and JS on [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/).

Comment: The problem is variable name. If you change it to something like `function myClick(){}` it would work.

Answer (score 1):

Your first function doesn't work because `click()` is a **built-in function** in JavaScript which simulates a mouse-click on an element. Here is a [demo](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_html_click). So when you click on the paragraph the built-in function is executed first instead of your function which displays the message through `alert()` function

Since your second function is an [anonymous function](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-anonymous-functions/) it executes without any error.

To solve it simply rename it to any other name except the name of a [built-in function](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_builtin_functions.htm). Refer the code snippet below for example.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<body>
  <script>
      function alertOnclick() {
        alert("You clicked on a paragraph");
      }
  </script>
  <p onclick="alertOnclick()" id="paragraph">
    This is a paragraph
  </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Went through your Code **@sb2021**

I think it is well resolved by **@rifkyniyas**

But I would like to give you a suggestion.
Try to place the script tag inclusions just before the closing of body tag. Placing scripts at the bottom of the  element improves the display speed, because script interpretation slows down the display.

**Something just like this**

```
<body>
.
.
.
.
.
.
<script>...</script>
</body>
```

[Check this out](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_whereto.asp)

Also, non-interactive elements with click handlers must be avoided. A good practice!